# Jenkins is not able to pull code from private bitbucket cloud repo

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to connect bitbucket private repo to jenkins. I have setup a webhook in Bitbucket. As well as added credentials to Jenkins. Still my build is getting stuck and not able to pull the source from Bitbucket. 
I know it's only in private repo, because i have tried to connect with public bitbucket repo and it worked fine.

here is the error i am getting in jenkins

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/test2.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:809)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1076)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1107)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1281)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1886)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1596)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:807)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.jvnet.winp.WinpException: Failed to read RT_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS error=299 at envvar-cmdline.cpp:151
    at org.jvnet.winp.Native.getCmdLineAndEnvVars(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.parseCmdLineAndEnvVars(WinProcess.java:126)
    at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.getCommandLine(WinProcess.java:102)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$WindowsOSProcess.getArguments(ProcessTree.java:451)
    at hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildKillingVeto.vetoProcessKilling(MsBuildKillingVeto.java:56)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.getVeto(ProcessTree.java:243)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$WindowsOSProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:429)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree.killAll(ProcessTree.java:146)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.destroy(Proc.java:380)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:353)
    at hudson.Proc.joinWithTimeout(Proc.java:166)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1873)
    ... 15 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Further research:**

1) I am able to run the same command (C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/release/*) in same location (Jenkins workspace) - It's successfully fetching remote repo.

2) Jenkins able to fetch and download public repo content.

3) This is first time setup with all updated plugins as,

Git plugin - 3.3.1
Git client plugin - 2.4.6
Credentials plugin - 2.1.13
Jenkins - 2.59

I don't think up what else can be there, because of it jenkins not able to run commands?

can someone please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checklist of things that may fail:

- [The plugin version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698437/jenkins-error-performing-git-command)
- [Wrong Password](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38655)
- Special Characters in the password ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421890/jenkins-git-plugin) and [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38655))
- Have you tried changing the protocol? Instead of https go for git://
  or ssh://
- Have you updated the plugin recently?
- Have you tried a downgrade of the plugin?
- Have you updated both, [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)?

**EDIT:**

- **Solution:** Have you tried with a different repo?

Comment: I am using Git plugin 3.3.0 and credentials plugin 2.1.13. I am sure password is correct as i updated password couple of times to make sure it. I have special character in my password "parenthesis". Do you think it can be issue?

Comment: I have updated my repo password and removed special character. Still getting same error.

Comment: I have tried with http and ssh both. Getting same error. I am trying this setup first time. So, using this plugin first time. Jenkins version - 2.59, Git plugin - 3.3.0 and Credntials plugin - 2.1.13

Comment: Did you updated the git client version? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin

Comment: I just noticed, i don't have git client plugin installed. I install it and kick off the build. still same error. For SSH. i am getting another error, Git is not identifying the repo URL for ssh. After installing Git client plugin, Do i need to configure anything for that plugin?

Comment: I just mentioned Git client if you were doing things with git within your job.  Could you try creating a new private repo in bitbucket (an empty one, maybe with one file) and fetch from there?

Comment: Yes, You are correct. After installing Git client plugin. I was trying with old repository and that was the issue. I created new repo and it worked. Thanks a lot....